# Can I pass my InputStream directly in open ParcelFileDescriptor openFile() of ContentProvider?

Tags: android, inputstream, android-contentprovider, file-descriptor

I have an InputStream that I want to pass on to the openFile() method of a ContentProvider. Can I somehow pass my InputStream directly, somehow wrapping it in a ParcelFileDescriptor? Or do I have to create a pipe and then manually read from the InputStream and write to the OutputStream of the pipe? If I could, I'd like to just pass the stream along, but maybe it isn't possible?

Comment: you have to use a pipe, there is a helper method in ContentProvider for this

Comment: Thx. You can write it as an answer and I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use a pipe for that. fortunately there is a helper method for this that makes your life easier, see [openPipeHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#openPipeHelper(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20T,%20android.content.ContentProvider.PipeDataWriter%3CT%3E))